# Php export to msword file

Tags: php, html, css

I'd like to know how to export html content to ms word.

Here is my code.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<b>My first document</b>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Succeed to export msword file but how could I use css code like border-radius?

I used style='border-radius:50%' but it is not working.

Anyhelp would be appreciate.

I'd like to know how to do style work of that doc file.

Comment: Word doesn't support that.

Comment: naming a html  file *.doc, does not magically make it msword format